# Method to sum up all input values always returns 0

Tags: javascript, forms

Why do I get only zero in my calculation?

Code:

```
<?php echo 'AU$ <input type="text" name="pay_total" class="amount_text_change" id="amount_textbox_'.$i.'" onChange="UpdateValue_'.$i.'()" onKeyUp="AddInputs()"  value="1">'; ?>

<td>Total</td>
<td>AU$ <span id="Display"></span></td>
```

Javascript:

```
function AddInputs()
{
  var total = 0;
  //var coll = document.getElementsByTagName("input")
  var coll = document.getElementsByTagName("pay_total")

  for ( var i = 0; i<coll.length; i++)
  {
    var ele = coll[i];
    total += parseInt(ele.value);
  }

  var Display = document.getElementById("Display");
  Display.innerHTML = total;
}
```

This javascript will auto add everytime user enter a numeric value in the textbox, but it's strange, the result is zero, must be something missing, can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This...

```
document.getElementsByTagName("pay_total")
```

should be...

```
document.getElementsByName("pay_total")
```